# When UTF-8 encoded text is sent to database, special characters get corrupted

Tags: php, mysql, post, encoding, utf-8

I have a form that reads some data. And a php file that sends this data to the database. All of the html files and php file are UTF-8. When the form reads the data, I have a check with **`echo`** right before the INSERT statement. The **`echo`** displays the words correctly. But when it is sent to database, it arrives with broken characters.

For example:
I send the word "`Būve`". **`echo`** prints it exactly like that. But in the database I get "`BÅ«ve`". 
I have both of these right after connection as well.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

PHP code:

```
echo $_POST[pasutitajs];

$sql = "INSERT into ligumitable (nrpk, ligums, pasutitajs, parkstisanasdatums, summa,)  VALUES ('$_POST[nrpk]', '$_POST[ligums]', '$_POST[pasutitajs]', '$_POST[parkstisanasdatums]', '$_POST[summa]')";
```

Tables in the database are utf8 as well, if I unput the data through phpmyadmin, using these characters, everything is fine. It's the INSERT that breaks it. What could be wrong?

EDIT:

This is funny. Thing is, i am not the only one working on the code. And now that I checked it, my buddy used "$conn->query($sql)" and not "mysql_query($sql)". No idea why. I changed it to a regular mysql_query and it works. Thanks everyone, sorry for bothering you with such a simple thing.

Comment: BTW: You should use quotes to access your array values. (e.g. `$_POST['summa']` instead of `$_POST[summa]`.

Comment: use database collection as utf8_general_ci

Comment: Stupid point to rule out: you *are* using `mysql_query` to execute `$sql`, right? Do look here for a step by step checklist: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Comment: This is funny. Thing is, i am not the only one working on the code. And now that I checked it, my buddy used "$conn->query($sql)" and not "mysql_query($sql)". No idea why. I changed it to a regular mysql_query and it works. Thanks everyone, sorry for bothering you with such a simple thing.

Comment: Do not use the `mysql_*` interface, switch to `mysqli_*`.

Answer (score -1):

You can maybe fix it like this:

```html
$sql = utf8_decode("INSERT into ligumitable (nrpk, ligums, pasutitajs, parkstisanasdatums, summa,)  VALUES ('$_POST[nrpk]', '$_POST[ligums]', '$_POST[pasutitajs]', '$_POST[parkstisanasdatums]', '$_POST[summa]')");
```

Comment: Hmm.. Just tried it, now it puts question marks instead of these symbols. Like this: "B?ve". Could it it be a server-side issue?

Comment: You can run a replace function over the string, build up a PHP class with the characters that give issues and the HTML ascii code to replace them. That should fix it

Comment: God no, don't do that. "ū" isn't supported in the ISO-8859-1 encoding, which is why `utf8_decode` destroys it and also otherwise doesn't help.

Comment: Don't use utf8_decode, it just adds to the mess.

Answer (score -1):

before inserting data into database write this two line:

```
  $str="set names UTF8";
  mysql_query($con,$str);
```

in $con write your connection codes.

Comment: 1) The OP is already doing that. 2) The arguments to `mysql_query` need to be reversed.